# how to close browser session when we close any browser using JavaScript Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using below code for browser session expire when we close browser, From below code browser is closing as expected but If we click back button or if we enter in address url the session is expiring and it redirects to login page

ASP.net project
I have tried using onunload event when closing browser

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          var clicked = false;
          function CheckBrowser() {
              if (clicked == false) {
                  //Browser closed   
              } else {
                  //redirected
                  clicked = false;
              }
          }

          function bodyUnload() {
              if (clicked == false)//browser is closed  
              {
                  var request = GetRequest();
                  request.open("GET", window.location.origin + "/" + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] + "/Default.aspx", false);
                  request.send();
              }
          }

          function GetRequest() {
              var xmlhttp;
              if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
              else {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
              return xmlhttp;
          }
          $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 116 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 82)) {
                  clicked = true; //shortcuts for F5 and CTRL+F5 and CTRL+R

              }
           }); </script> <body onunload="bodyUnload();" onclick="clicked=true;">
```

in Default.aspx page i have clearing session in page load event

Browse session should clear when we close the browser but it should not impact on other keys when we press, currently if we press back button or reload button so browser session is clearing without calling onunload event in JavaScript

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to manually clear the session?

Comment: To programmers and managers of the world, please, please, please, stop pretending to manually manage the session.

Comment: in chrome settings -->Continue where you left off, It will not close the session when browser close, so manually clearing off with code, in normal settings browser is closing as expected but using above settings we need session clear in closing browser

Comment: Your last comment is unclear, anyway, manually clear the session is an antipattern. It is useless, and also it makes things uncomfortable for the user. Also it is meaningless, since it is automatically cleared in 20 minutes.

Comment: session automatically close in 20 mins but in my requirement suppose if I login my website and it shows dashboard after login and if we close the browser and re-open again then it is opening directly website dashboard instead of login page. Client requirement is if they close browser without signout and open browser again then it should not show dashboard directly instead it should show login page to authenticate again.